# Accessing Controller variable in ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am pretty new to web development and I have been working on a small project.

This is what I am trying to achieve. I have a badly nested JSON data for 10 products. This is the [data](http://m.lowes.com/IntegrationServices/resources/productList/json/v3_0/4294857975?langId=-1&storeId=10702&catalogId=10051&nValue=4294857975&storeNumber=0595&pageSize=20&firstRecord=0&refinements=5003703) I am using.

I have a "View More" button for each product for its specifications. The specifications can be accessed using the index as such **"products[index].ProductInfo.p_product_specs.Value"**. When I click on the "view more" button, I am routing to a different page viewmore.html. In the viewmore.html, I have this html code

```
<div ng-controller='mainController'>
    <div class="viewMore">
        <ul ng-repeat="spec in products[id].ProductInfo.p_product_specs.Value">
             {{ spec.Key }} : {{ spec.Value}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a function in the controller which return me the index of that product in the array "products" as soon as I click on the "View More" button.

```
$scope.viewmorefn = function(){
    var self = this;
    $scope.id = (function() {
        //some code which returns index, console.log gives correct results.
        return index;
    }                 
    )();
 }
```

But when I try to use "id" in the ng-repeat (in viewmore.html), it just doesn't work. Is there any way I can make "id" accessible in my viewmore.html page? Any help will be greatly appreciated, I have already given this 2 days. Thanks.

EDIT : @uowzd01 : I am not sure if the data is being lost. The controller has this:

```
$http.get(url)
    .success(function (result) {
                $scope.products = result.ProductsList;
         })
    .error( function (data, status) {
           console.log("Error retrieving data");  
 });
```

And in the viewmore.html I am able to interpolate "**{{ products }}**" and **{{ products[0].ProductInfo.p_product_specs.Value }}** and also the data of other objects if I specify the index explicitly.

EDIT 2: Complete code

HTML : First Page : product_list_page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css" /> 
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <div class="main">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
<div ng-controller='mainController'>   
        <div class="showProduct">
          <div ng-show="isShow" ng-mouseenter="isShow=true">
                <show-repeat></show-repeat>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="eproducts" ng-repeat="product in products">
            <div class="fixed-size-square"  ng-mouseenter="hoverIn()">
                <show-products></show-products>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

viewmore.html

```
<div>
    <div class="viewMore">
        <ul ng-repeat="spec in products[selfId].ProductInfo.p_product_specs.Value">
            <li> {{ spec.Key }} : {{ spec.Value}} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code :

```
var myApp =  angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$window', '$filter', '$http', function($scope, $window, $filter, $http){
    $http.get('data.txt')
    .success(function (result) {
                $scope.products = result.ProductsList;
             })
    .error( function (data, status) {
                console.log("Error retrieving data");  
    });

    $scope.hoverIn = function() {
        $scope.isShow = true;
        $scope.pr = this;
        $scope.price = this.product.ProductInfo.p_product_price;
    }

    $scope.hoverOut = function() {
        $scope.isShow = false;   
    }

    $scope.returnPrice = function() {
        $window.alert('The price is $' + $scope.price);
    }


    $scope.viewmorefn = function(){
        var self = this;
        $scope.selfId = (function() {
            var count = 0;
            var str1 = self.product.ProductInfo.Brand + self.product.ProductInfo.p_product_description;
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < $scope.products.length ; i++)
            {
               var str2 = $scope.products[i].ProductInfo.Brand + $scope.products[i].ProductInfo.p_product_description;
               if(str1 === str2)
                   break;
               count = count + 1;
            }
            return count;
        }                 
      )();
      console.log('id is : ' +$scope.selfId);
    }
}]);

myApp.directive("showRepeat", function(){
    return {
        template : '<img class="lgImage" src="{{ pr.product.imageURLs.lg }}"> <br / > <div class="descText"> {{ pr.product.ProductInfo.Brand }} {{ pr.product.ProductInfo.p_product_description }} <br /> <div class="divClass"> <ul class="descList" ng-repeat="spec in pr.product.ProductInfo.p_product_specs.Value | newFilter"> <li> {{ spec.Key }} </li> </ul> </div> </div> <span class="priceText"> {{ product.ProductInfo.p_product_price | currency }} <br /> </span> <button id="cartBtn" ng-click="returnPrice()">Add to Cart</button> <br /> <div class="priceTop">{{ pr.product.ProductInfo.p_product_price | currency }} </div>'
    }
});

myApp.directive("showProducts", function(){
    return {
        template : '<div class="prdList"><br /><img class="showprdimg" src="{{ product.imageURLs.sm }}"><br /><br/> <div class="spanText">{{ product.ProductInfo.Brand }} {{ product.ProductInfo.p_product_description }} </div> <br /><br/> <div class="priceText">{{ product.ProductInfo.p_product_price | currency }} </div><br/><a href="#/viewmore">"<button id="viewMoreBtn" ng-click="viewmorefn()">View More</button></a></div>'
    }
});


myApp.filter('newFilter', function(){
    return function(newSpec) {
        var out = [];
        angular.forEach(newSpec, function (newSpec) {
            if((newSpec.Key === 'ENERGY STAR Qualified') && (newSpec.Value ==='Yes')) {
                out.push(newSpec);   
            }
        });
        return out;
    }
});

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the view more page
        .when('/viewmore', {
            templateUrl : 'viewmore.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })
});
```

Comment: Try a different name as idProduct as id is a reserved attribute from AngularJS. Not sure if you'll fix your issue. Also you must use [$scope.apply()](https://goo.gl/4GGlyl), so the AngularJS will be notified that you changed $scope.

Comment: it could because you are navigating to a different page, the mainController get recreated and all the data is gone. you syntax looks fine. are you using just 1 controller for 2 pages?

Comment: @LeoCaseiro Changing name doesn't work. I will look into $scope.apply().

Comment: @Peter I guess that's what I am doing. I am calling the function on button click, then setting the id there, which I am trying to use in ng-repeat.

Comment: @uowzd01 I have just 1 controller for both pages.

Comment: I don't believe it has anything to do with the function, nor $scope.apply().

Comment: I think the primary issue is related to controller instantiation.  If you instantiate mainController again as a child of another instance of mainController you are going to have some $scope issues.  On top of the fact that you simply shouldn't do that.  If there is no instance of mainController outside the template you have no means of passing the index to ng-repeat

Comment: @KumarAnand if you can display the data by setting the index explicitly, then the only cause is the id itself is not return the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/orbx5kfq7wlB0ReIfVbQ?p=preview)

First, to clear some of the dust - though it is not the specific problem, you are instantiating the same controller numerous times - in your HTML and ngRoute.  Pick one, not both.  I got rid of the ng-controller directives in your HTML, so it just uses ngRoute now.  However, because you are calling the same controller for both views, the controller is losing it's values because you are getting a new instance of the controller.  It is also fetching the same data twice.  While it technically is working, it's really bad JavaScript.  You should look at ui-router and do some nested views and instantiate the controller one time and fetch the data one time.

To get it working, I essentially created a service to store the index value in:

```
myApp.factory('theIndex', function() {
  return {
    val: ''
  }
})
```

When the controller loads, it pulls whatever value is stored in the service, and when you click the View More button, it stores the index value in the service.

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$window', '$filter', '$http', 'theIndex', function($scope, $window, $filter, $http, theIndex){
    $scope.selfId = theIndex.val;  // get whatever index value is stored, if any
 //... buncha stuff
 $scope.viewmorefn = function(){
        var self = this;
        $scope.selfId = (function() {
            var count = 0;
            var str1 = self.product.ProductInfo.Brand + self.product.ProductInfo.p_product_description;
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < $scope.products.length ; i++)
            {
               var str2 = $scope.products[i].ProductInfo.Brand + $scope.products[i].ProductInfo.p_product_description;
               if(str1 === str2)
                   break;
               count = count + 1;
            }
            return count;
        }                 
      )();
      theIndex.val = $scope.selfId  // set the index value here
      console.log('id is : ' +$scope.selfId);
    }
}]);
```

The plunker provided is updated, using all your supplied code.  Don't forget to inject the new service into your controller.  This should get you up and running, though as I said before, it's pretty ugly.

Comment: I think I am accessing the data correctly, please see the EDIT in original post. I will work on the other inputs you have provided. Thank you.

Comment: it must not be receiving the index then, which could be accounted for by a $scope issue because you are instantiating mainController inside your template.  Remove that from the template and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only reason. Removing the template didn't work. There is one more thing, I am calling the function "viewmorefn()" from a directive. Can that be the issue here?

Comment: Can you verify that the function is actually being called?  I think you really need to post more code.  Post the directive as well as your mainController code.  And your main html where you instantiate the controller.

Comment: I have posted my entire code, please have a look. It's badly written, apologies for that.

Comment: remove ng-controller="mainController" from all HTML.  You are using ngRoute to assign instantiate controllers already.

Comment: You Sir, are a life saver. Worked like a charm. Thanks a billion. I am just 2 weeks old in JavaScript, so bad code. Your explanation taught me some new things, thanks for that too.

Comment: No worries. Services/factories are singletons, but controllers are not.  A challenge most people new to angular face is getting stuff between controllers.  Services are one good way to do that.